# How do I solve "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pheweb.command_line'"

Tags: python, linux, installation

I am trying to run a software called 'Pheweb' on Ubuntu.
I followed the [guideline here](https://github.com/statgen/pheweb)
but got `'permission denied'` error when I ran `'pip3 install pheweb'`. So I installed with this code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev libz-dev libffi-dev
sudo python3 -m pip install wheel cython
sudo python3 -m pip install pheweb
```

as the guideline author suggests in the `'detailed install instructions'`.

I wanted to check that it's properly installed by typing `'pheweb --help'`
but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pheweb", line 5, in <module>
    from pheweb.command_line import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pheweb.command_line'
```

**This is what else I've tried:**

1. The author states the below proceedure in 'the detailed install instructions' and I tried this but still got the same error;

```
If installation was successful but the command pheweb --help is not found, 
you need to add pheweb to your PATH. You should be able to just run echo 
'PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc, start a new terminal, and try 
pheweb --help again.
```

2. When I run this code:

```
sudo python3 -m pip show pheweb
```

I get this result:

```
Name: PheWeb
Version: 1.3.16
Summary: A tool for building PheWAS websites from association files
Home-page: <https://github.com/statgen/pheweb>
Author: Peter VandeHaar
Author-email: pjvh@umich.edu
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: boltons, cffi, Flask, Flask-Compress, Flask-Login, gevent, gunicorn, intervaltree, numpy, psutil, pysam, rauth, requests, scipy, tqdm, wget
```

I tried adding

```
PATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:$PATH"
```

to `~/.bashrc` as well but I still got the same error.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command:

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Run the following command:
   `echo 'PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`
3. Press Enter.
4. Close the terminal window.
5. Open a new terminal window.
6. Run the following command:
   `pheweb --help`

To find out where the pheweb command is located, you can run the following command:

`which pheweb`

This will print the path to the pheweb command. If the output of this command is blank, then the pheweb command is not installed on your system.

Try adding the `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` directory to your PATH variable.

If the pheweb command is installed on your system, but it is not in your PATH environment variable, you can add it to your PATH by editing your `~/.bashrc` file. Open the `~/.bashrc file` in a text editor and add the following line to the end of the file:

`PATH="/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:$PATH"`
Save the ~/.bashrc file and close the text editor.
Then, open a new terminal window and run the following command:

`source ~/.bashrc`
This will reload your PATH environment variable. Now, you should be able to run the pheweb command without any problems.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried as you have written but still got the same error. I ran "which pheweb" and the terminal said "/usr/local/bin/pheweb". Could there be any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: I have edited my answer. If none of the things worked try to uninstall and install it. If this also doesn't work create a new virtual environment.